# Vite CommonJS Resolver throws Unexpected Token Error when importing ESM

Tags: create-react-app, es6-modules, vite, commonjs

I have a create-react-app project I'm migrating to Vite. That project uses "styled-components" like this:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const someDiv = styled.div`...`;
```

Now the issue comes up when running `vite build`:

```
vite v4.0.2 building for production...
✓ 51 modules transformed.
[commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (1:167492) in /project/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js
file: /project/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:1:167492
1: import{typeOf as e,isElement as t,isValidElementType as n}from"react-is";import r,{useState as o,useContext as i,useMemo as s,useEffect as a,useRef as c,createElement as u,useDebugValue as l,useLayoutEffect as d}from"react";import h from"shallowequal";import p from"@emotion/stylis";import f from"@emotion/unitless";import m from"@emotion/is-prop-valid";import y from"hoist-non-react-statics";function // ... rest of file
```

So it seems like it is trying to import `styled-components.browser.esm.js` using the commonjs--resolver, but there are `import` statements at the top of that file and it seems to get confused.

Any ideas why the "Unexpected token" error might happen and how this can be resolved? Shouldn't it import it as ESM?

UPDATE 07/02/2023:
On a Github discussion it was noticed by someone else, that everything works when there is no `define` block in the `vite.config.ts`: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/11495.
However, this is a questionable solution if you actually need to define something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12246) with Vite and it turns out the issues is about how `define` works, it replaces the word "process" everywhere with what is put into `define` in the vite config, leading to the syntax/token errors.

Detailed answer is here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12246#issuecomment-1450153095

Answer (score 0):

From Vite documentation: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

- For JavaScript strings, you can break the string up with a Unicode zero-width space, e.g. 'import.meta\u200b.env.MODE'.
- For Vue templates or other HTML that gets compiled into JavaScript strings, you can use the  tag, e.g. import.meta.env.MODE

So my `define` became:

```
 define: {
    'process.<wbr>env': {}
```